# Fig support on Boot2Docker / Windows platform

Tags: docker, boot2docker, fig

I am trying to get started with with Docker & Fig using the official Boot2Docker framework.

The Fig website includes instructions for getting Fig working on OS-X (http://blog.docker.com/2014/10/fig-1-0-boot2docker-compatibility-and-more/). However, there are no references for getting Fig working within Boot2Docker under Windows.

I tried the instructions for installing Fig within Boot2Docker from the fig website at http://www.fig.sh/install.html, and ran into a roadblock with this command:

```
  curl -L https://github.com/docker/fig/releases/download/1.0.1/fig-`uname -s`-`uname -m` > /usr/local/bin/fig; chmod +x /usr/local/bin/fig
```

Apparently the Boot2Docker filesystem is read-only, so the curl command fails.

Can someone assist me with getting Fig working with Boot2Docker under Windows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up adding an alias to the boot2docker VM (by editing the default user .profile):

```sh
alias fig='docker run --rm -it \
        -v $(pwd):/app \
        -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
        -e FIG_PROJECT_NAME=$(basename $(pwd)) \
        dduportal/fig'
```

This actually creates a docker container for running the fig command. The first invocation takes a minute or two, but afterwards it's pretty seamless.

Answer cribbed from: https://github.com/docker/fig/issues/598

Comment: @rjoxford asks, "Can I trouble you to explain where this goes? The link suggests adding it into bootlocal.sh, can't find this... Thanks"

Comment: There's a hidden file called ".profile" in the user home directory. You can see it by typing "cd ~" then "ls -la". Edit the file (you can use vi) and add the alias line I mentioned above. Next time you start the docker shell, you should be able to use fig.

Answer (score 0):

When you log in into boot2docker, you caa run "sudo -s" and do that action as root.

Comment: That works to a point - sudo allows me to write to the filesystem (which I previously thought was read-only). However, fig is a 64 bit executable, which doesn't work within the boot2docker container - see https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/issues/603 .